# Using Ajax Assigned Variable With Subsequent PHP Code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some php and jquery/js that passes the value of a text box to php using ajax.
The ajax call is wrapped in a function that is activated by a button.
I have assigned the content of the textbox to $filename.
How do I now use the variable $filename in subsequent php code.
I tried adding it to the success event but nothing appears to be happening.

The textbox and button code:

```
<input type="text" size="17" maxlength="21" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />

<input type="button" onclick="GetDate()" value="Click" />
```

The script:

```
function GetDate(){

    var filename = $('#datepicker').val();

    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {filename: filename},       
       success: function(data){
       var $filename = (data);
       console.log('Date Succesfully Captured: ' + $filename);       

       <?php
        $filename = "upload/".$filename. ".txt";
        $sheetData = file_get_contents($filename);
        echo $sheetData;
       ?>


       }
    });
}
```

The external php file (ajaxfile.php):

```
 $filename = $_POST['filename'];
  echo $filename;
```

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You can't use it in the subsequent PHP code. That code runs when you first open the page. The only PHP code that runs when the AJAX request happens is `ajaxfile.php`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Lot to learn still. I thought it would only run on the button click.

Comment: You need to understand how PHP is run by a webserver.

Comment: The JS runs on the button click, but the PHP runs to create the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax was somehow corrupting the text file data. It works fine using isset directly from the web page, so I have stored the textbox value in a cookie using JavaScript. The following code is working without issue to get the value of the cookie, covert to name of the textfile, get the textfile contents and store it in the $sheetData variable which is usedused by the jQuery table creator script. It is not corrupting the text file and works without issue.

```
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{        
    $tmpdatepicker =  $_COOKIE["datepicker"];
    $filename = "upload/" . $tmpdatepicker . ".txt";
    $sheetData = file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code in the first file runs when you open the page, it's too early to use the variable.

You should have `ajaxfile.php` read the file and send the contents, then you can use that in the JavaScript code.

`ajaxfile.php`

```
$filename = $_POST['filename']; // You really should validate this, 
                                // to prevent the user from reading any file on the server
readfile("upload/$filename.txt");
```

```
function GetDate() {
  var filename = $('#datepicker').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxfile.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      filename: filename
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#date").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Barmar. The data is not written to the console but the value of filename is visible in a debug. Could it be that it is not a date but a string? The format is 2019-08-04_2019-08-10. I intend to append .txt to it to get the filename. I guess I do this in the php file?

Comment: I forgot the `upload/` directory.

Comment: If you use `readfile()` it should output the contents of the file, not the filename.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. the console log shows the contents of the text file. Now I need to figure out how to pass that file content back to JavaScript/jQuery where I have code all ready and working to use it (I have tested it by manually specifying the filename).

Comment: It should be in the `data` variable in the `success` function.

Comment: sorry to bother you but I have been trying to resolve this for a long time. When I pass the data to my script that populates a jQery table only a few of the entries are usable. The rest reports NaN. I had some success when i did it manually using file_get_contents("2019-08-04_2019-08-10.txt"), where I had to specify the filename as i had not figured out the ajax by then. I am having trouble putting this together in the php file instead of readfile. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: `readfile($filename)` is the same as `$contents = file_get_contents($filename); echo  $contents;`. I don't see any way this can cause you to get `NaN`, unless that's what's in the file.

Comment: Oh OK thanks. When I did it manually specifying the filename and using isset it worked OK. The file contents are good. It is just zeros and ones separated by commas and [ ]. No matter what I try with file_get_contents the value of data is always empty, or what looks like a return character.

Comment: it is used to populate a jQuery table where one is a different background color to zero.

Comment: If the filename is correct, `readfile` should work the same as `file_get_contents`. I can't tell what you might be doing wrong from your vague descriptions. I don't know if the problem is in your PHP code or the JavaScript that processes the response. You should post a new question and show what you're trying to do, it's no longer the same as this question.

Comment: No worries. I will put together a new post. many thanks for all your help. it was really appreciated.